# ¿Por qué al instanciar una clase externa, no me deja acceder a sus métodos "static" y cuando les remuevo el "static", sí?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, class

Me encuentro realizando una `aplicación` de escritorio, en la cual implemento `clases` externas para optimizar mi `código`, pero me surgió una incógnita que no logro entender. Ejemplo:

```
private ClaseExterna instancia = new ClaseExterna ();
```

De esta manera creo la `ìnstanca` de la `clase` externa que voy a utilizar, en la cual contiene `métodos/funciones` estáticos. De antemano ya sé que los `métodos estáticos` le pertenecen a la `clase` que los contiene.

Entonces como son `estáticos`, la manera de acceder a ellos es así:

(supongamos que la **`claseExterna`** contiene estos `métodos`)

```
public static void metodo1(){
  //lógica
}

public void metodo2(){
  //lógica
}
```

En este ejemplo, para llamar al método `estatico` `metodo1()`, sencillamente lo hago de esta manera:

```
ClaseExterna.metodo1();
```

Pero si quiero llamar el `metodo2()` de la misma manera, sé que no se podrá, ya que dicho `método` no le pertenece a la `clase` que lo contiene, por lo tanto se debe crear una `instancia` para acceder al `metodo2()`.

Y es aquí donde surgió la incógnita, al momento de crear la instancia antes mencionada

> **private ClaseExterna instancia = new ClaseExterna ();**

Pude llamar al `metodo2()` de esta manera: `instancia.metodo2()`, pero cuando quise llamar al `metodo1()` con dicha `instancia` no me permitió acceder a él.

Solamente quisiera saber el porqué de ese comportamiento al intentar acceder a `métodos estáticos` y `no estáticos`. No sé si hay alguna manera de poder acceder a ambos, independientemente de que sean `éstáticos` o no.

Comment: Veo que tu mismo explicas correctamente como podrías acceder que sería con `ClaseExterna.metodo1();`. No puedes acceder desde tu instancia porque desde un objeto dinámico no se puede acceder a un método estático.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas las especificaciones del lenguaje C#, para un mejor uso de el. Aquí te dejo un link que te puede ayudar. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ Suerte!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Me parece que tu mismo te respondiste:

> De antemano ya sé que los métodos estáticos le pertenecen a la clase
>   que los contiene.

Mira aqui una mejor explicacion de lo que escribiste desde la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static):

> Use el modificador `static` para declarar un miembro estático, **que
>   pertenece al tipo en sí y no a un objeto específico**

El tipo al que se refiere la documentación es la declaración de la clase:

```
public class ClaseExterna ◄ tipo
{
  //...
}
```

Mientras que la instancia es la creación de un objeto en memoria:

```
   instancia
      ▼
var clase = new ClaseExterna();
```

Por lo que desde una instancia, no puedes acceder a lo que esta marcado como `static` porque pertenece al tipo.